# Salesforce surveys with community

Tags: survey

I am trying to implement salesforce survey using flow and process builder. I have created a flow which creates survey invitation record whenever case status is changes, i am assigning its participant id to parent contact of the updated case.

I have process builder which launches this flow on case record change. But I am receiving following error :

> RECORD CREATE: Create_Survey_Invitation
>   Create one SurveyInvitation record where:
>   CommunityId = {!communityId} (0DB2E000000g1UaWAI)
>   Email__c = {!contactEmail} (gaikwad.priyanka24@gmail.com)
>   Name = {!formula_surveyName} (Survey for Case 00001029)
>   OptionsAllowGuestUserResponse = true
>   OptionsCollectAnonymousResponse = true
>   ParticipantId = {!contactId} (0032E00002T9AYzQAN)
>   SurveyId = {!surveyId} (0Kd2E000000kf5fSAA)
>   Result
>   Failed to create record.
>
> Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Because this is an anonymous survey, remove the participant ID and try again.. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception suggests:

> Because this is an anonymous survey, remove the participant ID and try again..

You are assigning a `ParticpantId` on an anonymous survey, which in this case is determined by the value `OptionsCollectAnonymousResponse = true` thus resulting in the error.

You will need to either remove the Participant Id or set the value of `OptionsCollectAnonymousResponse` to `false`.